# how to find number of interfaces used in a class in c#?

Tags: c#

i am expecting the **number of interfaces implemented in class** at compile time and run time.

As i am new to c# so please explain in detail or post a link.

Comment: Did you want this info at compile time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get count of interfaces -

```
<your-class-name> myobject = new <your-class-name>();
int count = myobject.GetType().GetInterfaces().Count();
```

And more refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfaces(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (Type tinterface in <your-object>.GetType().GetInterfaces())
{
   Console.WriteLine(tinterface.ToString());
}
```

You can use `GetInterfaces` method for this as shown above.

To print number of interface do this.

```
Console.WriteLine(<your-object>.GetType().GetInterfaces().Length.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Type[] interfaces = typeof(MyType).GetInterfaces();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
 int numberOfImplementedInterfaces = typeof(Class_name_here).GetInterfaces().Length; // Gives the count of implemented interfaces
 var Interfaces = typeof(Class_name_here).GetInterfaces(); // Gives the collection of interfaces
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via Reflection. Specifically the `GetInterfaces` [Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfaces(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
foreach (Type tinterface in typeof(MyType).GetInterfaces())
{
    Console.WriteLine(tinterface.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This loop will print all the interfaces used in class. but i need the count of interfaces used in class.

Comment: @abhishek Yes. If you follow the link in my post you will see that the method provides an array. From there is is a simple exercise to determine the array's length.